# _.memoize only cache's first argument

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I realized today that the _memoize function only caches results for the first argument provided.

```
function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
var sum = _.memoize(add);
console.log(sum(1,2));
>>> 3
console.log(sum(1,5));
>>> 3
```

Is this a bug or deliberate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Deliberate. [Relevant docs](http://underscorejs.org/#memoize):

> The default hashFunction just uses the first argument to the memoized function as the key.

But good news is you can change this behaviour by introducing your own hash function.

```js
function myInefficientHashFunction() {
  // not really an efficient hash function
  return JSON.stringify(arguments);
}

function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
var sum = _.memoize(add, myInefficientHashFunction);

document.getElementById('one_two').textContent = sum(1, 2)
document.getElementById('one_three').textContent = sum(1, 3)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
<div>1 + 2 = <span id="one_two"/></div>
<div>1 + 3 = <span id="one_three"/></div>
```

Comment: It's worth noting, in case anyone plans on using this code, that stringifying `arguments` actually interprets it as an object with numeric keys, not an array.  `Array.apply(null, arguments)` will turn it into a proper array, which will stringify to something significantly shorter.

Comment: @AaronDufour: Yup, it's not called `myInefficientHashFunction` for nothing. :) However, note that you need to pay attention to what you are memoising; if your hash function is doing more work than the function you are trying to memoise, you shouldn't do it. Thus, you should be handcrafting your hash function to be as simple as possible while still being unique on the domain of your memoised function.

Comment: To clarify, OP, what I'm saying is, don't use this code literally, it's just an example. Only you know what kinds of arguments your function accepts, and thus only you can make a good hashing function (fast, giving a unique result for a unique input, and returning as memory-efficient result as possible, ideally a number).

Answer (score 0):

```
const g = _.memoize(([a, b]) => a + b)
console.log(g([1, 2]))
console.log(g([1, 3]))
console.log(g([1, 4]))
```

pass all as the first argument